# Altium Designer - Move an object only horizontally

Tags: altium

Is there an easy method to move an object only in the horizontal direction? I know what there is the "Move Selection by X, Y, ..." command but I am looking for something that uses the cursor, since I want to be able to visualize the change in real time. For example, sometimes I need to move designators around but I still want it to be in line with other designators .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press and hold the "Alt" key and then move the object with the cursor in the left or right direction.

Note: This also works in the up/down and 45 degree angle directions.

Comment: Thanks! its a common feature in adobe packages eg photoshop which made me try it in Altium too.

Comment: I can move my object (without pressing any key) in any direction while holding it with the mouse cursor. I use version 16. Which version are you referring to?

Comment: @Sachin The point is that if you hold down the Alt key while moving with the cursor it restricts the movement to multiples of 45 degrees only.

Comment: @DerStrom8: This is cool! Never knew this existed!

Comment: @Sachin Me neither, which is why I'm very thankful this user mentioned it. I would accept this as the correct answer.

Comment: @DerStrom8: Oh yes! I agree with you on that

Answer (score 3):

Usually when I need to do this I just click and hold whatever I want to move and I use the arrow keys on the keyboard to move it only in a certain direction. If it's going too slowly using the arrow keys, hold down shift while you press the keys and it will move faster (by a factor of about ten, I believe).

Comment: And just like 'shift' fastens your speed in that direction, you can use 'ctrl' for reducing the speed by the same factor.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches I use for this. The first is [alignment tools](http://www.altium.com/documentation/15.1/display/ADES/PCB_Dlg-AlignComponentsDialog((Align+Objects+(PCB)+))_AD).
Note the object you select first is often what the other objects align for.
Alternatively, I double click the object and modify its x or y directly. This is a little cumbersome but its very accurate. Knowing exact x and y coordinates helps keep everything inline.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just change the grid in the non-travel dimension only to something large, so that a mouse-move won't be able to drag it in that direction.

Doing this (different grid size for X and Y-directions) and then changing the reference point is a technique I often use when designing component footprints.